# Why is it just pass? i want to know more i need explained

Tags: javascript, if-statement, scope, closures

I wrote another answer. But I don't understand this.

[image]

.. although, I run chrome debugger but I cant understand well.

```
result = true
// is passed
```

I don't understand well. I submit another answer but I want to know why is it just pass.
I need explain more and I would like to fix from this code.

```
function isPrime(num) {
let result;
for(let i = 1 ; i <= num ; i++) {
  if(num[i] / num[i] === 1 && num[i] / num[i] === num[i]){
    result = true
  } else {
    result = false
  }
}
  return result
}
debugger;
let output = isPrime(2);
console.log(output); // --> true

output = isPrime(6);
console.log(output); // --> false

output = isPrime(17);
console.log(output); // --> true
```

Comment: This definitely isn't a valid function for determining whether a number is prime or not. `result` is getting overwritten in every iteration of i, which means only the last iteration/test matters. And that's not right

Comment: @ControlAltDel overwritten... Why is it being overwritten? what makes this happen ?

Comment: "Why is it being overwitten?" Because you are changing *result* in every iteration

Comment: Regarding the behavior you're observing while debugging, in the screenshot you're in the first iteration of the loop (i.e. `i` is set to `1`). Execution is stopped on line 7 which indicates that the `else` block is being executed. **That means the assignment on line 5 was skipped, which is why `result` still contains the value `undefined`.** After another step in debugger, once the statement in line 7 is executed, `result` will then have the value `false` assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikipedia,

> A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that is not a product of two smaller natural numbers. For example, 5 is prime because the only ways of writing it as a product, 1 × 5 or 5 × 1, involve 5 itself.

```
function isPrime (num) {
  // step 1: filter 1, negative numbers and decimal numbers
  if (num === 1 || num < 0 || num % 1 !== 0) {
    return false;
  }

  // step 2: dividing num by smaller numbers
  let divisor = num - 1;

  while (divisor > 1) {
    const remainder = num % divisor;

    // if num is divisible by dividing a smaller number, it's not a prime
    if (remainder === 0) {
      return false;
    }

    divisor -= 1;
  }

  // num is a prime
  return true;
}

let output = isPrime(2);
console.log(output); // --> true

output = isPrime(6);
console.log(output); // --> false

output = isPrime(17);
console.log(output); // --> true

output = isPrime(1);
console.log(output); // --> false

output = isPrime(-12);
console.log(output); // --> false

output = isPrime(78.25);
console.log(output); // --> false

output = isPrime(-12.5);
console.log(output); // --> false
```